# Accessing extra information from a SharePoint OData feed in an SSIS package

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, rss, odata

I inherited an SSIS project with over 40 separate packages that read data from various Sharepoint lists.  The connections are all OData Feeds.  The feeds are all lists of files.  I am trying to access the URL of each file but that information doesn't appear to be in the part of feed that SSIS can read.

When I look at the data returned from the feed, I only see the information inside the children of "properties."  Is there a way to access the other information from the feed? Specifically the "src" in the content node.

I am using VS 2015 to edit the packages.

Here is a sample of the feed I am trying to read:

```
<feed 
  xml:base="http://www.sharepointURL.com/consumer/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title type="text">ConsumerInquiryLibrary</title>
<id>http://www.sharepointURL.com/consumer/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ConsumerInquiryLibrary</id>
<updated>2016-10-05T19:27:55Z</updated>
<link rel="self" title="ConsumerInquiryLibrary" href="ConsumerInquiryLibrary" />
<entry m:etag="W/&quot;1&quot;">
  <id>http://www.sharepointURL.com/consumer/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ConsumerInquiryLibrary(3)</id>
  <title type="text"></title>
  <updated>2009-01-26T13:55:24-05:00</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link m:etag="&quot;{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000},1&quot;" rel="edit-media" title="ConsumerInquiryLibraryItem" href="ConsumerInquiryLibrary(3)/$value" />
  <link rel="edit" title="ConsumerInquiryLibraryItem" href="ConsumerInquiryLibrary(3)" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="ConsumerInquiryLibrary(3)/CreatedBy" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="ConsumerInquiryLibrary(3)/ModifiedBy" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CheckedOutTo" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CheckedOutTo" href="ConsumerInquiryLibrary(3)/CheckedOutTo" />
  <category term="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ConsumerInquiryLibraryItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />

  <!-- I need access to the URL In the following Node -->
  <content type="application/octetstream" src="http://www.sharepointURL.com/consumer/Consumer%20Inquiry%20Library/DocumentTitle.pdf" />
  <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
  <!-- It appears I only have access to the following elements -->
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:Id>
    <d:ContentTypeID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:ContentTypeID>
    <d:ContentType>Document</d:ContentType>
    <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2009-01-26T13:55:24</d:Created>
    <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">20</d:CreatedById>
    <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2009-01-26T13:55:24</d:Modified>
    <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">20</d:ModifiedById>
    <d:CopySource m:null="true"></d:CopySource>
    <d:ApprovalStatus>0</d:ApprovalStatus>
    <d:Path>/xxx/yyy</d:Path>
    <d:CheckedOutToId m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true"></d:CheckedOutToId>
    <d:Name>DocumentTitle.pdf</d:Name>
    <d:VirusStatus>42282</d:VirusStatus>
    <d:IsCurrentVersion m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsCurrentVersion>
    <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Owshiddenversion>
    <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
    <d:Title m:null="true"></d:Title>
  <!--  End of the elements I can access-->
  </m:properties>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 0):

After working on many other aspects of the project, I finally came back around to this issue.

I looked through all of the available data from the feed and came up with a workable solution.

I was able to use the "Path" property in conjunction with base URL of the site (passed via a project parameter) and the "Name" to construct a file reader.

One package down, 44 to go!